# Custom keyboard with key components commands not feeding through

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm creating a custom on-screen keyboard to keep the appearance consistent within my program.
I decided to have each key be a custom component which feeds a command hosted on the `Keyboard` component through to the button part of the `Key`. That way I can use the same `Key` component for the special keys as well.

The `Key` component works fine when hosted straight on the main window, but when I try to run it through the `Keyboard` component, the command does not execute.

The intent is to have the letter or number on the `Key` be added to the `Text` property of the keyboard. I will deal with special keys later.

`Key` snippet:

```xml
<UserControl
    x:Name="ThisKey"
    >
    <Grid>
        <Button
            Command="{Binding Command, ElementName=ThisKey}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding CommandParameter, ElementName=ThisKey}"
            />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Where `Command` and `CommandParameter` are defined as:

```cs
public ICommand Command
{
    get => (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty);
    set => SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    nameof(Command),
    typeof(ICommand),
    typeof(Key),
    new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

public object CommandParameter
{
    get => GetValue(CommandParameterProperty);
    set => SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value);
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandParameterProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    nameof(CommandParameter),
    typeof(object),
    typeof(Key),
    new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));
```

Within the `Keyboard` component, I call `Key`s as follows:

```xml
<local:Key
    Command={Binding KeyCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:Keyboard}}"
    CommandParameter="0"
    />
```

Where `KeyCommand` is defined as:

```cs
private RelayCommand KeyCommandRelay;
public ICommand KeyCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (KeyCommandRelay == null)
        {
            KeyCommandRelay = new RelayCommand(
                    param => KeyCommand_Executed(param),
                    param => true
                    );
        }
        return KeyCommandRelay;
    }
}
private void KeyCommand_Executed(object param)
{
    //Text is a string property of Keyboard.
    Text += (string)param;
    //This is here to prove to me that the button is pressed, to rule out errors with Text.
    MessageBox.Show((string)param);
}
```

Placing the `Key` directly in the window has the command working fine, however it does not execute the command when forming part of the `Keyboard`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that I had renamed the command on the keyboard but not renamed it in the XAML. Besides that, I had also typoed it with "KeyButtom" instead of the original name "Keybutton".